# Java MySQL selecting multiple rows while summing one column

Tags: mysql, sum

```
String sql = "SELECT TYPE, SOURCE, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT FROM INCOME WHERE TYPE = 'EARNED' " + 
                    "AND DATE BETWEEN '" + year + "-" + month + "-" + "01' AND '" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "'";
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

I have an Income table that holds all income wheather it be investment, business, paycheck or whatever.  I want to pull the total of each type.  I have reduced all possible income into 3 types, earned, portfolio, or passive.  I want to get the sum(amount) for each in one resultset.  The above code only selects the total for the earned type but I can not figure out how to get the other two types included.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

```
String sql1 = "SELECT TYPE, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT " + 
               "FROM INCOME " +  
               "WHERE DATE BETWEEN '" + year + "-" + month + "-" + "01' " + 
               "AND '" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "'"+
               "GROUP BY TYPE " ;
stmt = conn.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
```

This query would give you the sum of amount by each type (earned, portfolio, or passive)- If these are the 3 types in your income table

Try modifying this way

Comment: Your query is with incorrect  syntax and will not run

Comment: Wow that was fast response.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This is called conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'EARNED' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS EARNED_cnt,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'PASSIVE' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS PASSIVE_cnt,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'PORFOLIO' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS PORFOLIO_cnt
FROM INCOME
```

Comment: Isn't `GROUP BY` a better alternative here?

Comment: Oh actually it does it differently. While in your case you'll have a column for each sum, `GROUP BY` will create a row for each sum.

Comment: @YassinHajaj That's what I figured he wants.

Comment: OK that is getting closer to what I am going for however, the table is laid out horizontaly like so... Type, Source, Amount with 3 rows one for each type Earned, Portfolio, and Passive.  Any way to make it happen like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should place group by to end of statement.

```
String sql = "SELECT TYPE, SOURCE, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
    FROM INCOME WHERE DATE BETWEEN '" +
    year + "-" + month + "-" + "01' AND '" +
    year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "' GROUP BY TYPE"; 
stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```